# The original icon of an android app is not showing, showing default apk green logo in live app

Tags: android, android-webview, google-play-console, appicon

**The original icon of an android app is not showing, showing default apk green logo in live app**

my app status is in production and visible in play store, after install app from play store the original icon of an android app is not showing, showing default apk green logo

while checking in android studio there is showing original app icon of my android app but after installing from play store the original icon of an android app is not showing, showing default apk green logo.

please help.

Thank you .

here is my Manifest file code

```
<application
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.FoodyBazar"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you did not include the icon for all sizes.

> ## Use [Image Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio)
>
> To start Image Asset Studio, follow these steps:
>
> 1. In the Project window, select the Android view.
> 2. Right-click the res folder and select New > Image Asset.
>    [image]
> 3. Continue by following the steps to:
>
>    - If your app supports Android 8.0, create adaptive and legacy launcher icons.
>    - If your app supports versions no higher than Android 7.1, create a legacy launcher icon only.
>    - Create an action bar or tab icon.
>    - Create a notification icon.